# How much space std::unordered_map and boost::unordered_map reserve for buckets and why?

Tags: c++, boost, hashmap, g++, unordered-map

When you insert elements into `unordered_map` and new number of elements is greater than `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()` the container grows (number of buckets grows) and rehashing occurs.

I did a simple experiment: I created an allocator, which prints the size of allocated memory every time method `allocate(size_type n)` is called and use it with `unordered_map`. In a loop I inserted new elements into this container (one element in each iteration).

For `std::unordered_map` I got these numbers:
`2, 5, 11, 23, 47, 97, 199, 409, 823, 1741, 3739, 7517, 15173, 30727, 62233, 126271`
and for `boost`:
`18, 30, 54, 98, 194, 390, 770, 1544, 3080, 6152, 12290, 24594, 49158, 98318`

My question is: What is the strategy which `std::unordered_map` and `boost::unordered_map` use to determine the following numbers of buckets to create? Are these numbers hardcoded or calculated? Why such strategies are cosidered to be good?

Edit:
Implementation depends on compiler. I use gcc 7.5 and boost 1.65.1 but any answer (for any implementation) would be interesting.

Comment: Note that standard library implementations differ between compilers. The standard prescribes a behaviour, not a particular implementation.